# GCP: You do not have sufficient permissions to SSH into this instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh-tunnel, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-console

I have a (non-admin) account on one GCP project.

When I start the Dataproc cluster, GCP spins up 3 VMs. When I try to access one of the VM via **SSH (in browser)** I get the following error:

[image]

I tried to add recommended permissions, but I cannot add the **iam.serviceAccounts.actAs** permission.

[image]

Any idea how to solve this? I read through the GCP documentation, but I just cannot find the solution for this. I have the following roles associated with my account:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If from console you want to click the "SSH" button next to an instance but face this issue, you can grant the `Service Account User` role instead of `Editor`, and it should resolve this.

If you're using OS Login, you may need the `Compute OS Login` role as well, but SA user should work.

If you're using IAP, you may need the `IAP-secured Tunnel User` role (or `roles/iap.tunnelResourceAccessor` in CLI)

Before:
[image: recreate issue]

After adding `Service Account User` role:
[image]

If you want to access remotely, use a bastion and Cloud IAP tunnel. [Here is an example setup/teardown](https://gist.github.com/mikesparr/c420a2d827e79a496c39f03b08b56de5) (NAT and router optional if you want to configure your bastion or install packages)

Comment: `Service Account User` role was exactly what I needed

Answer (score 3):

In the end, we managed to solve it by granting users the *Editor* permission on *Compute Engine default service account*. Not sure it is the right way but it seems to work.

[image]

Comment: I have the exact same issue, but your solution didn't work for me. Do you find any alternative solution to this? here's my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50184382/compute-engine-ssh-you-do-not-have-sufficient-permissions-to-ssh-into-this-inst

Answer (score 0):

I believe the latest documentation on Compute Engine SSH access is here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access

It seems that you have to enable OS Login on the specific instance(s) you want to SSH into.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an ID under a role for a specific instance somehow did not work for us

[image]

However, when the same ID was assigned the same role under IAM, it worked

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Official docs: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/access-overview

For **OS Login** https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin/set-up-oslogin :

- `roles/compute.osLogin`, which doesn't grant administrator permissions
- `roles/compute.osAdminLogin`, which grants administrator permissions

If you use **IAP** additionally you have to add: `roles/iap.tunnelResourceAccessor`, see https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/managing-access